How to configure log shipping for encrypted dbs correctly?
I want to configure log shipping for databases. In sys.databases, I can see that some of my databases are encrypted true and some have is_master_key_encrypted_by_server true.
How do I handle the above 2 cases with log shipping.

You use the same appoach as restore encrypted database on different instance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149776/restoring-encrypted-database-on-another-server-using-backup-encryption

copy encryption cert to secondary server

This article by Ashok Kumar explains how to set log shipping for an enabled database.

Does this apply for both encrypted database and also for database having master key encrypted by server? @SqlWorldWide

Yes. There is a section  "restore Master key which we backedup on primary and Open Master Key and Create certificate which we created and Backed up on Primary ". You need to understand why, and when the is_master_key_encrypted_by_server column is set to true.

@BrendanMcCaffrey - is that answer for encrypted db or is_master_key_encrypted_by_server db?
